# Different size support android?

Tags: android

I know it is more general question but i am curious about that.Android is supporting different size we know about it.My question is when you are development how can solve this issue generally.You can prepare icons for all different size or you are using ninepatch?

Are you using all drwable folder or just big one? if you are using ninepatch ,can we use for background also?

Comment: here you go, bro. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I know this.I am just curious about developers way.I see a lot of ways on the project.Generally how is using?Because  if you have 10 screen all icons size can be hard for design team.

Comment: thats the way I do it, and people I know that do it. It's really not hard to create an icon with 3 different sizes. I'm sure it can get hectic when you have a lot of them, but i'm pretty positive thats the best way to do it.

Comment: I use both, depending on what I'm doing. If there's not a lot of graphics I just use the default one (layout-mdpi).

Comment: @Bill but when you use just mdpi and open large screen icon will be bad i think

Comment: I forgot to mention I do use 3 different size icons, just use mdpi for the other graphics in some of my apps, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9 patch can be used for background and other things as well but generally for things that are resolution independent. For icons etc, it's recommended to use icons with different sizes, they are placed in the folders named - drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi and drawable-xhdpi for low, medium, high and extra high density screens respectively. Density independent bitmaps can be placed in drawable-nodpi. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html for more.

Comment: so its should be bulky file size(.apk) right, carrying all resource for single screen size i.e Iam having hdpi device. That apk will contains all l,m and x drawables also?.

Comment: absolutely! Unless you don't want your app to look nice in all display densities.